# Cant find a way to add all of my views into UIScrollview Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift4

**This is  my code i have made ui programmatically but  i am not able to make it scroll able  **

Here is my code I have tried many methods to add scroll view programmatically but it did not worked out plz help

```
 var cityname_EN: String?
 var cityname_DE: String?
 var country: String?
 var text_EN: String?
 var text_DE: String?

var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var imageView: UIImageView!

let labelOne: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Scroll Top"
label.backgroundColor = .red
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
return label
}()

let labelTwo: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Scroll Bottom"
    label.backgroundColor = .green
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()



let allImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "all"))
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return imageView
}()


let citynameELable:UILabel = {

    let citynameELable = UILabel()


    citynameELable.textColor = UIColor.darkText
    citynameELable.textAlignment = .center
    citynameELable.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    citynameELable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return citynameELable

}()

let countryLable:UILabel = {

    let countryLable = UILabel()


    countryLable.textColor = UIColor.darkText
    countryLable.textAlignment = .center
    countryLable.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    countryLable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return countryLable

}()


let textELable: UITextView = {

    let textELable = UITextView()
    textELable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textELable.textAlignment = .center
    textELable.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    textELable.isEditable = false
    textELable.isScrollEnabled = false
    return textELable
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    setupNavigation()
 setupLayout()


}




func setupNavigation(){

    navigationItem.title = "Map View"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

    navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes =
        [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray,
         NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30) ??
            UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)]

}



private func setupLayout()
{

    view.addSubview(countryLable)
    view.addSubview(citynameELable)
    view.addSubview(textELable)

    citynameELable.text = cityname_EN
    countryLable.text = country

    textELable.text = text_EN

    let topMapBokContainerView = UIView()
    topMapBokContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    topMapBokContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let mySegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl (items: ["English","DE"])




    mySegmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    mySegmentedControl.accessibilityActivate()

    mySegmentedControl.isEnabledForSegment(at: 0)

    mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    // Add function to handle Value Changed events
    mySegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.segmentedValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)




    let bottomControlsStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [citynameELable,countryLable])
    bottomControlsStackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    bottomControlsStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bottomControlsStackView.distribution = .fillEqually





    view.addSubview(topMapBokContainerView)




    topMapBokContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    topMapBokContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    topMapBokContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    topMapBokContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true



    topMapBokContainerView.addSubview(allImageView)


    allImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topMapBokContainerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    allImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topMapBokContainerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    allImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topMapBokContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true



    self.view.addSubview(mySegmentedControl)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mySegmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topMapBokContainerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10 ),

        mySegmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        mySegmentedControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        mySegmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)

        ])

    view.addSubview(bottomControlsStackView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        bottomControlsStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySegmentedControl.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10 ),

        bottomControlsStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        bottomControlsStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        bottomControlsStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)

        ])

    view.addSubview(textELable)

    textELable.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomControlsStackView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    textELable.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    textELable.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    textELable.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


}

@objc func segmentedValueChanged(_ sender:UISegmentedControl!)
{

    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        citynameELable.text = cityname_EN
        textELable.text = text_EN
    }
    else if  sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

        citynameELable.text = cityname_DE
        textELable.text = text_DE

    }


}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

All the view i have created i tried to add to a scroll view  like `view.addSubView(MyViews Here)`

[Here is the screen shot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Er2f.png)

Comment: If you are adding into the scrollView, you need to set the offset for each view... either x or y. I guess that is the reason the aren't getting added in the scrollView

Comment: ok let me see the of set

Answer (score 0):

1. Set Constraints Top, Bottom, Leading and Trailing to ScrollView referencing SuperView
2. Super View add Scroll View (view.addSubview(scrollView))
3. Create a content View and set constraints Top, Bottom, Leading and Trailing to content view Referencing Scroll View
4. Add the Content view to ScrollView (scrollView.addSubview(contentView))
5. Set the elements in content View

Comment: I tried these methods  but the content inside the scroll view do not scroll

Answer (score 0):

According to your question your views hierarchy should be:

**view -> scrollView -> allYourViews**

So you can set your scrollView frame the same as the view and then:

```
view.addSubView(scrollView)
scrollView.addSubView(yourViews Here)
```